# Get Method with Params returning null always

Tags: java, spring, jpa, h2

I'm trying to made a search query with a @GetMapping
Using JPA and SpringBoot

Here is the controller Method used:

```
    @GetMapping("/search{min_price}{max_price}{text}")
    public Optional<Product> searchProducts(@PathVariable(required = false) Integer min_price,
                                            @PathVariable(required = false) Integer max_price,
                                            @PathVariable(required = false) String text
    ) {
        Optional<Product> products = productRepository.SearchProduct(min_price, max_price, text);
        return products;
    }
```

And here the @Query that I made in repository: (I Changed the @Param names to ?X and the issue still happens)

```
    @Query("SELECT P FROM Product P " +
            "where (P.name like CONCAT('%',lower(?3),'%') or P.description like CONCAT('%',lower(?3),'%')) " +
            "and (?2 is null or P.price <= ?2) " +
            "and (?1 is null or P.price >= ?1)")
    Optional<Product> SearchProduct(@Param("max_price") Integer min_price,
                                    @Param("min_price") Integer max_price,
                                    @Param("text") String text);
```

I'm using H2 database for the first time, don't know if the ?X is the right way to use the variables in it. (in PL-SQL I use :X for this purpose).

When I made a get the return is always "null" in Postman

this is an example of get that I made "search?min_price=1&max_price=200&text=prod"
The database has 5 entries and if I search with this values direct in DB 2 results match the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either delimit the path parameters by `/`

```
@GetMapping("/search/{min_price}/{max_price}/{text}")
```

and update your client request to match, or use `@RequestParam` instead

```
public Optional<Product> searchProducts(@RequestParam Integer min_price,
                    @RequestParam Integer max_price,
                    @RequestParam String text)
```

Comment: If I use / to delimit I need to use this / in get URL right? Then I need to use the RequestParam to this.

But about the way to refer to variables in H2, is correct use ?1, ?2, ?3 to refer to them respecting the order given in function?

Actually, I think it worked:
query did not return a unique result: 2

Now I just need to check this. Thank you

Comment: these 2 options are mutually exclusive. your current URL pattern requires `@RequestParam` to read the parameters. If you want to use `@PathVariable` then you need to use something like `/search/1/200/prod`

Comment: I can fix all the issues here. You tip saved me haha
Thank a lot.